# bad URI(is not URI?): {"message":"d64","type":"success"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httprequest, httpresponse, httparty

Am using httparty to send API request, I want to get output response after i sent request,

```
url = HTTParty.post("https://example.com/api/sendhttp.php",
                        :query => { :authkey => "authkeyvalue",
                                    :mobiles => mobileNos,
                                    :message => messages,
                                    :sender => "senderid",
                                    :route => "routeid",
                                    :response => 'json'
                                   })

    response = HTTParty.get(url)
    puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

But when i run above code it throws bad `URI(is not URI?): {"message":"d64","type":"success"}` error. How to solve it and get the response?

Comment: Does your real url contain spaces? : https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are running a POST to https://example.com/api/sendhttp.php with JSON format, this succeeds, and you're getting a response of:

```
{"message":"d64","type":"success"}
```

So your `url` variable now contains `{"message":"d64","type":"success"}`, which is clearly not a valid URL, so when you try to do a GET on it, you get an error. You've already got a response from the first POST, you should perhaps parse this? You don't need to do

`response = HTTPParty.get(url)`

unless you're expecting a second GET request to a URL which is returned by the first.